# How would I make two ways to output something with <<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

For example, if I wanted to have a default version of outputting with `<<` and a detailed version.

```
myClass myObject(//Constructor parameters);

cout << myObject << "\n";
cout << myObject.detailed << "\n";
```

I tried making a modifier within my class but that didn't seem to work.

```
class myClass {
public:
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const myClass& myObject);
   std::ostream& detailed(std::ostream& output);
}
```

That gave the error "Reference to non-static member function must be called".

Comment: `cout << myObject.detailed << "\n";` is `::operator<<(::operator<<(cout, myObject.detailed), "\n");`. It explains where you are wrong.

Comment: You perhaps want `detailed` to be a steam manipulator.

Comment: @273K Yes but how can the "detailed" flag be stored in the stream? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Let `myClass::detailed()` return `std::string`.

Comment: Normally the syntax would be `<< detailed(my_object)`. But since it's now widely agreed that the whole `ostream` infrastructure is inferior to `std::format`, I suggest to learn about writing custom `std::formatter`s instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know how stream manipulators work. I am actually asking is there a way to make the syntax `stream << detailed_manipulator << my_object` work, but it just seems impossible. Then it is not very useful to define manipulators for user-defined classes. Of course the syntax by `@HolyBlackCat can work, but then it is no longer a manipulator.

Comment: @WeijunZhou "*I am actually asking is there a way to make the syntax `stream << detailed_manipulator << my_object` work*" - there is a way to make that **syntax** work, yes. But it won't **behave** the way you want. That is simply not how `operator<< works. Parameter-less manipulators are not aware of subsequent values.

Comment: I guess my confusion is about the terminology. I used to believe that only things like `std::setw` that somehow change the future behavior of a stream can be called manipulators, but now I checked the standard library and realized things like `std::put_money` can also be called manipulators, so I have no more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my approach is the same as what @RemyLebeau but more generic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class templated to be able to apply
// detailed mechanism to different types

template<typename type_t>
class detailed
{
public:
    detailed(const type_t& object) : 
        m_object{ object } 
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const detailed<type_t>& detailed_object)
    {
        detailed_object.m_object.detailed_output(os);
        return os;
    }

private:
    const type_t& m_object;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// like your class

struct test_class_t
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test_class_t& object)
    {
        os << object.basic;
        return os;
    }

    void detailed_output(std::ostream& os) const // <- const is important
    {
        os << basic << ", " << details;
    }

private:
    std::string basic{ "basic" };
    std::string details{ "details" };
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    test_class_t object;
    std::cout << detailed{object} << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think you need to define another type template above the operator<< overload. I had a problem with overloading << in a different template class and that would fix it. Also I just tried your solution and it worked as intended (although I use detailed() instead of detailed{} ). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I use {} to show it is a constructor and not a function call.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how it is supposed to be done according to the iostreams design.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    static const int flagId; // private format flag
  public:
    int x, y; // for exposition only
    static std::ios_base& detailed(std::ios_base& str) {
        str.iword(flagId) = true;
        return str;
    }
    static std::ios_base& abridged(std::ios_base& str) {
        str.iword(flagId) = false;
        return str;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& myClassObj) {
        if (stream.iword(flagId)) {
            stream << "X=" << myClassObj.x << " Y=" << myClassObj.y;
            // optionally reset the flag to false
        } else {
            stream << myClassObj.x;
        }
        return stream;
    }
};

const int MyClass::flagId = std::ios_base::xalloc();

int main()
{
    MyClass myObject{1, 42};
    std::cout << MyClass::detailed << myObject << "\n";
    std::cout << MyClass::abridged << myObject << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The key here is, of course, the use of `xalloc` and `iword`, to allow adding custom formatting flags. (Depending on what the difference is in the formatting, it might make sense to hijack one of the existing flags, but in general, I don't think that this is a good idea.) You might also consider whether you want to make any change permanent (which is what the above, and is consistent with most of the standard manipulators), or reset it to some default value each time it's used, like `setw`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a non-static class method to `operator<<`, it does not support the ability to call that method, hence the error.

For what you are attempting to do, you can change `detailed` to be a *stream manipulator* object instead of a member function, eg:

```
struct detailed {
    const myClass &cls;
    detailed(const myClass &cls) : cls(cls) {} 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const detailed& det) {
        // print details about det.cls as needed...
        return os;
    }
};


myClass myObject(...);

cout << detailed(myObject) << "\n";
```

For example, this is how standard parametered manipulators like `std::(re)setiosflags`, `std::set(base|fill|precision|w)`, `std::quoted`, etc are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* I just saw the [answer by @n. m. could be an AI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77576330/22193627). He show how to create an I/O manipulator without an argument! I thought it could not be done. There is still a lot of good information below, however, so, read on, as you wish.

The OP is trying to code an I/O manipulator that does not take an argument, and use it to output the members of a class. The first part of this answer explains why that won't work [unless, that is, you take a different tack, and use the method of n. m.]. You have to use a manipulator with an argument in order to achieve the OP's goal. The second part of the this answer explains how to do that.

The other answers posted here do not use the forward declaration, nor the extra friend declaration, used by this answer. [Except for the answer by n. m.,] that means that *the I/O manipulators they define can only access the public members* of class `myClass`. This answer shows how to get access to the private members.

##### I/O Manipulators with no arguments

I/O manipulators, such as `std::boolapha`, are functions that take a stream reference as their only argument.

It is as though `boolalpha` (for output streams) had the following definition:

```cpp
std::ostream& boolalpha( std::ostream& ost)
{
    // Set the appropriate format flag, and then... 
    return ost;
}
```

Note that this is not how `boolapha` is actually implemented. It is, however, how you can implement your own manipulator:

```cpp
std::ostream& myManipulator( std::ostream& ost)
{
    // Use `ost` in some way, either by outputting something, 
    // or by modifying its settings. Then...
    return ost;
}
```

When you insert a manipulator that takes no arguments into a stream, you invoke `operator<<` with *the address of the manipulator function*.

```cpp
   std::cout << myManipulator;  // Uses the address of function `myManipulator`
```

This works because there are special overloads of `operator<<` that are defined precisely to match the signatures of functions like `myManipulatr`. Those are part of the Standard Library. You do not have to write them.

Let's try it.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& myManipulator(std::ostream& ost)
{
    ost << "myManipulator sets the width to 25, and the fill character to '*'.\n"
        << std::setfill('*')
        << std::setw(25);
    return ost;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << myManipulator << 42 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
myManipulator sets the width to 25, and the fill character to '*'.
***********************42
```

##### No room for the `this` pointer

Given the mechanics described above, there is no mechanism for passing the `this` pointer in an I/O manipulator that does not take any arguments.

You might try coding your own `operator<<` overload that takes a pointer to a member function as its argument, but that won't work. A pointer-to-member can only be invoked by providing an object.

Here is [what they say at isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#addr-of-memfn)

> In C++, member functions have an implicit parameter which points to the object (the this pointer inside the member function). Normal C functions can be thought of as having a different calling convention from member functions, so the types of their pointers (pointer-to-member-function vs pointer-to-function) are different and incompatible. C++ introduces a new type of pointer, called a pointer-to-member, which can be invoked only by providing an object.

It is not possible, therefore, to create the I/O manipulator described in the OP [unless, that is, you use the very different method of n. m.].

But don't despair. You can create a manipulator that takes an argument.

##### An I/O manipulator with an argument

For this example, we give `myClass` two string variables. One should be output when detail is requested. Otherwise, the regular string should be output. Both are private.

Note the forward declaration of class `detailed`. That's needed for the second `operator<<` function, which takes a reference to a `detailed` object as one of its arguments.

```cpp
class detailed;

class myClass
{
    std::string regular{ "Regular: no detail" };
    std::string detail{ "Detailed: too much information" };
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, myClass const& mc)
    {
        // Call this function for "regular" output.
        ost << mc.regular;
        return ost;
    }

    // The friend declaration below is the only modification you need to 
    // make in `myClass`. Friendship give access to the private members, 
    // so you don't need to clutter `myClass` with debugging details used 
    // for "detailed" output.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, detailed const& d);
};
```

Next, define class `detailed`, which holds a reference to a `myClass` object. We are using `const&`, because we don't want the I/O manipulator to modify a `myClass` object. Class `detailed` uses the *hidden friend* idiom to define the `operator<<` function used for detailed output. That's where the clutter goes.

```cpp
class detailed
{
    // Storing a reference can lead to UB, so you take a risk if you 
    // use this class for anything besides its intended use, i.e., 
    // as a manipulator.
    myClass const& mc;
public:
    explicit detailed(myClass const& mc)
        : mc{ mc }
    {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, detailed const& d)
    {
        // Call this function for "detailed" output. 
        // Put all the "clutter" here. You can access all the members 
        // of class `myClass`, both public and private.
        ost << d.mc.detail << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
};
```

When you want detailed output, invoke the constructor of class `detailed` with a `myClass` object as its argument. The constructor creates a temporary, `detailed` object as a *proxy* , which is then output by `operator<<`.

```cpp
    myClass myObject;
    std::cout << detailed(myObject) << '\n';
```

Here is the complete program, including a two-line test driver.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class detailed;

class myClass
{
    std::string regular{ "Regular: no detail" };
    std::string detail{ "Detailed: too much information" };
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, myClass const& mc)
    {
        // Call this function for "regular" output.
        ost << mc.regular;
        return ost;
    }

    // The friend declaration below is the only modification you need to 
    // make in `myClass`. Friendship give access to the private members, 
    // so you don't need to clutter `myClass` with debugging details used 
    // for "detailed" output.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, detailed const& d);
};

class detailed
{
    // Storing a reference can lead to UB, so you take a risk if you 
    // use this class for anything besides its intended use, i.e., 
    // as a manipulator.
    myClass const& mc;
public:
    explicit detailed(myClass const& mc)
        : mc{ mc }
    {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, detailed const& d)
    {
        // Call this function for "detailed" output. 
        // Put all the "clutter" here. You can access all the members 
        // of class `myClass`, both public and private.
        ost << d.mc.detail << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myClass myObject;
    std::cout
        << myObject << '\n'
        << detailed(myObject) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Regular: no detail
Detailed: too much information
```

##### Function `info` – A simple alternative

In my own projects, I often add member function `info` to a class when I need debugging information. Function `info` returns a `std::string` which contains the state of an object. This is the solution suggested by @dimich in the comments.

These days, I like to use `std::format` to create the information string, but in the past, I generally used a `std::stringstream`.

```cpp
class myClass
{
    std::string regular{ "Regular: no detail" };
    std::string detail{ "Detailed: too much information" };
public:
    auto info(std::string_view heading) const
    {
        return std::format(
            "{}"
            "\n  regular : {}"
            "\n  detail  : {}"
            "\n"
            , heading, regular, detail
        );
    }
    // the rest of `myClass`...
};
```

Getting debug information is trivial. Here, I am "debugging" function `foo`:

```cpp
void foo(myClass& myObject)
{
    std::cout << myObject.info("myObject, entering function `foo`");
    // ...
    std::cout << myObject.info("myObject, exiting function `foo`");
}
```